# How to fire when click li element (react-paginate)

Tags: reactjs, react-paginate

guys. Thanks reading this question.

I want to fire a page change event when the button created by react-paginate is clicked, but I can't get it to work.

If using `react-paginate`. this create a DOM like below.

```
<ul>
  <li><a>1</a><li>
  <li><a>2</a><li>
  <li><a>3</a><li>
<ul>
```

I think this component fired onClick event when clicked `<a>`  only.
For example.　I created page-nation button like below.

[image]

If I clicked part of background-color(white), don't fire event of change page.
because don't clicked `<a>` tag(number) (that created by react-paginate automatically).

I want to fire to change page event on clicked `<li>` tag.
How to solve this?
do you know any idea?

Comment: what about stretch `a` to `li` size?

Comment: Thanks!! I can solve this!  @RamanNikitsenka

Answer (score 0):

I add css like below.

```html
a {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```